# Mock or mimic the Flash(EEPROM) for unit tests on Windows(Visual Studio framework)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, unit-testing, embedded, flash-memory

I'm working on creating a hardware mock for flash storage that is on embedded system (about 6Mb.) The mock will be used entirely for unit tests on Windows and Visual Studio Cpp Unit Test Framework.

I was wondering what is the best approach on this? Should I create a file(txt or binary) that has the exact size of the flash on hardware. Or, maybe create an array(or struct with storage blocks) on RAM with that size..

Answer (score 2):

On windows 6MB is nothing. Just keep it memory. You may add some functionality to save and load to/from the disk.